# Having to manually set permission to enable cam and microphone for 1-1 calls

Tags: video

We are using agora in a platform for 1-1 chats. 
Suddenly today the calls wont start until we manually change the browser settings.

What can be the reason for this?

It worked fine before, everything launched automatic

Comment: How is this about programming?

Comment: and how is your comment helping ?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for questions regarding programming (see the [tour]). If this question is not about programming, then it is not on topic for this site, and I could refer you to another site where it might be on topic (like [sf] or [su]).